# Changing Margin in LaTeX

Tags: latex, margin, title

I'm new to LaTex and I wanted to know how I can change the Margins of my *scrreport* so that the chapter title, text and basically everythin starts a bit higher and ends a bit lower. In my opinion there is too much empty space before anything starts.

If I use this simple example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrreport}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

I think the margins from top and bottom are too big. So i want everything to move up a little bit.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] so we have some code to start with?

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1:

Choose one of the predefined layouts. You'll find a list of available options in the koma script documentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,DIV=15]{scrreport}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

#### Method 2:

Setting up the text area manually. You should be really sure that you know what you are doing to get an aesthetically pleasant result.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrreport}

\areaset[current]{168.00mm}{250mm}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```